# Ux Capsule is not appended with Firmware Capsule

Tags: fwupd

In my Ubuntu 22.04 the kernel version of Ubuntu was v5.15.0. I updated the kernel version of Ubuntu to v5.16.0 or later by manual to check this issue. I found when the Ubuntu kernel was less than v5.19.0 and Ubuntu version was 22.04 and secure boot was disabled, I test flashing system firmware via fwupdmgr.

> The Ux Capsule was appended with firmware capsule.

After I updated the Ubuntu kernel to v5.19.0, I used the same way to flash system firmware via fwupdmgr.

> The Ux capsule was not appended with firmware capsule.